# error: cannot find symbol @TypeConverters({Converters_kotlin.class}) into a Room Database

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I was developing an App where I have the intention to keep data into a RoomDatabase.

I get the erro on the title when I try to sart my App.

I don't know if it for using a kotlin class in combination with other java class.

My kotlin file is the Converters.class with I use to keep Image into the database.

Converters.kotlin

```
class Converters_kotlin {

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromBitmap(bitmap:Bitmap): ByteArray{

        val outputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream)

        return outputStream.toByteArray()
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toBitmap(byteArray: ByteArray):Bitmap{

        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.size)

    }
}
```

Birddb.java

```
@Database(
        entities = {BirdRoom.class},
        version = 1
)
@TypeConverters({Converters_kotlin.class})
public abstract class Birddb extends RoomDatabase {
    private static volatile Birddb INSTANCE;
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 1;
    static final ExecutorService databaseWriteExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);
    public abstract BirdDAO birdDAO();



    public static Birddb getDatabase(final Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (Birddb.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            Birddb.class, "user_database")
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

And the fragment where I call the database:

CaptureFragment.java

```
public class CaptureFragment extends Fragment {

    private CaptureViewModel mViewModel;
    private ImageButton btnCamara;
    private ImageView mPhotoImageView;

    public static final int REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PHOTO = 0 /*1*/;
    private String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    private Uri photoURI;
    private EditText Ettitulo;


    public static CaptureFragment newInstance() {
        return new CaptureFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        Ettitulo = (EditText) container.findViewById(R.id.EtInstantanea);

        mPhotoImageView = (ImageView) container.findViewById(R.id.imgCapture);
        mPhotoImageView.setImageDrawable(null);

        btnCamara = (ImageButton) container.findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
        btnCamara.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                //1.Open the camera.

                if (v == mPhotoImageView) {

                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                            Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) getContext(),
                                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

                        } else {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) getContext(),
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                    225);
                        }


                        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) getContext(),
                                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

                        } else {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) getContext(),
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                    226);
                        }
                    } else {
                        dispatchTakePictureIntent();
                    }
                }

                //2. Recover the photo and write into internal storage.
                //TODO: Use AlerrtDiolog para solicitar nombre de la foto.
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which){
                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:

                                //Send the Jornal, and keep into DB.

                                String titulo = Ettitulo.getText().toString();

                                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                bundle.putString("edtValue", titulo);
                                bundle.putString("image", mCurrentPhotoPath);

                                //Swicth the () -> fragment
                                FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
                                FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
                                JournalFragment jf = new JournalFragment();
                                jf.setArguments(bundle);
                                transaction.replace(container.getId(),jf);
                                transaction.commit();

                                break;

                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                //No button clicked

                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Foto NO añadida a su diario personal.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                };

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                        .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();

                Intent intento1 = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File foto = new File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null), mCurrentPhotoPath);
                intento1.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(foto));
                startActivity(intento1);

                //3. Set the photo into the ImageView,
                Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null)+"/"+Ettitulo.getText().toString());

                Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap1);

                mPhotoImageView.setImageDrawable(d);

                //4. Ask if the user want to keep that pjoto into his jornal.

                AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                builder1.setMessage("¿Le gustaría guardar esta foto en su diario?");
                builder1.setCancelable(true);

                builder1.setPositiveButton(
                        "Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                //Instancio la BBDD local..
                                Birddb db = Room.databaseBuilder(getContext(),
                                        Birddb.class, "database-name").build();


                                //Añado el objeto Bird a la BBDD local.
                                BirdDAO birdDAO = db.birdDAO();
                                //List<Bird> users = userDao.getAll();
                                AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {

                                        //Guardar Objeto Bird en la BBDD.


                                        String descripcion = Ettitulo.getText().toString();
                                        BirdRoom bird = new BirdRoom(descripcion, mCurrentPhotoPath);
                                        Birddb.getDatabase(getContext()).birdDAO().insertBird(bird);
                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Ejemplar añadido correctamente a su diario", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });

                builder1.setNegativeButton(
                        "No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se ha añadido la foto actual a su diario", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                alert11.show();

            }
        });


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_capture, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(CaptureViewModel.class);

    }

    private void checkExternalStoragePermission() {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission((Activity)getContext(),
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            Log.e(TAG, "Permission not granted WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.");
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) getContext(),
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) getContext(),
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        225);
            }
        }if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Permission not granted CAMERA.");
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) getContext(),
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) getContext(),
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        226);
            }
        }

    }





    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "MyPicture");
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Photo taken on " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                photoURI = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

                //Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(AddActivity.this, "com.example.android.fileprovider", photoFile);

                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PHOTO);




            }
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), photoURI);
                mPhotoImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Ìf you guess how to solve it, take thanks for advance!

[EDIT]

Add a capture of the error return by Android Studio.

[image]

Comment: its `@TypeConverters({Converters_kotlin.class})` not `@TypeConverters(Converters_kotlin.class)`. Notice the brackets

Comment: Thanks for the answer @tyczj , but I try too, and doesn't work.Android Studio return the same error.